# How do I display an alert message on my ASP .NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, alert

This is not working:

```
try
{
     EnvironmentVerifier.VerifyAppFoldersAndFiles();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Error!", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
     Logger.LogError(ex.Source, ex.TargetSite.ToString(), ex.Message);
     return;
}
```

When the error occurs, it goes into the catch block but the alert message is not showing up. Am I missing anything?

Comment: What do you see in the page source?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Testifier - when the page loads up, right click on it and choose "view source" (wording might be different depending on your browser). This should show you the resultant HTML so you can check to see if your injected JavaScript is there or not, and if it is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Error!", "alert('" + ex.Message.Replace("'", @"\'") + "');", true);
```

The .Replace("'", @"\'") escapes your alert('message'); because if you have an error message like this:

```
alert('My error message's problem is that single quote.');
```

it will break unless you do this:

```
alert('My error message\'s problem is that single quote.');
```

Comment: Yes. I took a total guess, which is that your error message had a single quote in it somewhere and was breaking the javascript. I added a Replace function that would escape single quotes for you.